# wdActiveEndPageNumber returns a negative number

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to process headers based on the current page number in a Word macro:

```
Sub InsertHeader()
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim PageNumber As Integer
    Dim oSection As Section
    Dim oHeader As HeaderFooter
    For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
        If oSection.Index > 1 Then

        For Each oHeader In oSection.Headers
            oHeader.Range.Select
            PageNumber = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            If oHeader.Exists Then
                Select Case oHeader.Index
                Case Is = wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
                    If PageNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then
                        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("HeaderFirst"). _
    Insert Where:=Selection.Range
                    oHeader.Range.Select
                    Selection.Range.ShapeRange.Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.26)
                    End If
                    If PageNumber Mod 2 = 1 Then
                        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("HeaderFirst"). _
    Insert Where:=Selection.Range
                    End If
                End Select
            End If
        Next oHeader
        End If
    Next oSection

End Sub
```

When I execute this locally, the macro works fine. But when I run the same macro on a document that's opened from a network drive, the macro fails because `PageNumber` is given the value -1. Why would this be?

Edit: I had to revisit this macro, testing on a different machine revealed that it didn't run there either. To add insult to injury, the macro wouldn't run anymore in my original test environment.
In the end I solved the problem by changing the page layout so I wouldn't need this macro any more (I made a symmetrical page layout using the 'gutter' setting in the margins setup).
Still, the question stands: it looks like `wdActiveEndPageNumber` is not reliable. Maybe it's to do with calling this function from a header?

Comment: Concerning the `wdActiveEndPageNumber, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241714 shows that there are common problems with that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1` is returned because nothing was selected.
It appears that the page layout switches to draft without actually selecting anything on the first select.
Perhaps you can try to overcome the bug by switching back the layout before selecting:

```
oHeader.Range.Select
ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView
oHeader.Range.Select
Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Comment: I tested this, and can confirm that the page layout switches to Draft. When I add your code to my macro, I get an error message at the command `ActiveDocument.View = wdPrintView` saying 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. When I change that line to `ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView`, the macro works, both on my system and on the production machine.

Comment: Good it worked for you. I edited the code that you mentioned in my sample as well.

Answer (score 2):

wdActiveEndPageNumber was buggy in [Word 2002](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274003/EN-US).

From the MS website:

> This problem may occur when all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - The selected range contains a table.
>
> and
>
> - A page break occurs in the middle of a table row.
>
> and
>
> - The last cell in the row that contains the page break contains text that wraps to a new page.

Maybe this is the case also for you and your version of Word.